# Configure Netbeans to run tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, netbeans, jbehave

I have a project which does front end testing on a legacy application, it does not have it own function except selenium tests which run with jbehave stories.

My problem is i cant start the debug/run via the normall buttons in NB, i always have to find the Class and click on the "Test File" or on the "Debug Test File" button.

How can i confiure the project so this class gets tested regardles where i am in project? 
Or better somone explain to me how to do this the right way.

And this is what gets run when i try the file test and run:

```
cd C:\dev\xxxx\tests\xxxx.test; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dtest=at.dig.xxxx.tests.workflows.WorkflowStories -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Prelease-profile surefire:test\""
cd C:\dev\xxxx\tests\xxxx.test; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath at.dig.xxxx.tests.workflows.WorkflowStories clean test\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77\\bin\\java.exe\" -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Prelease-profile org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
```

This is my nbactions-release-profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath at.dig.eprocure.tests.workflows.WorkflowStories</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
                <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath at.dig.eprocure.tests.workflows.WorkflowStories</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>profile</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath at.dig.eprocure.tests.workflows.WorkflowStories</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Comment: In Eclipse there is `run/debug configuration` option, you define the class once there, and later you can easily run/debug using this configuration with a few clicks from mail menu. I belive that there must be a similar function in NetBeans.

Comment: Ye sadly there is no such option. I already know how i can run it on eclipse. But eclipse... is sooo slow.